# for-each not applicable to expression type

Tags: java

I'm having this error and I don't understand why. 
I'm a beginner in Java but I can understand for-each loop is only for iterable objects. Here I want to create the class `SetOfObjects` as an `ArrayList<SubObject>`. In `toString` method I have no problems with the loop but in `myFunction` I get the error.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
public class SetOfObjects {
    private ArrayList<SubObject> setOfObjects;

    public SetOfObjects(ArrayList<SubObjects> arr){
        this.setOfObjects = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String finalString = "";
        for (SubObject obj : setOfObjects) {
            finalString += obj.toString();
        }    
        return finalString;
    }

    public SetOfObjects myFunction(SetOfObjects aSet){
        for (SubObject obj : aSet) {    <----ERROR
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: `SetOfObjects` doesn't implement `Iterable<? extends SubObject>`.

Comment: Note that `setOfObjects` isn't a set, but a list. This is confusing. Either call it `objects` (or `listOfObjects`), or actually make it a `Set`.

Comment: On another note, use `StringBuilder` when doing multiple concatenations inside of a loop. When using the `+=` operator a new String object is created at every pass. StringBuilder reuses the same object for the whole loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SetOfObjects` doesn't implement `Iterable<? extends SubObject>` (nor is it an array). From [JLS 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> The type of the Expression must be Iterable or an array type (§10.1), or a compile-time error occurs.

Either iterate `aSet.setOfObjects` (assuming this is what you actually want to iterate over):

```
for (SubObject obj : aSet.setOfObjects) {
```

Or make `SetOfObjects` implement `Iterable<SubObject>`:

```
class SetOfObjects implements Iterable<SubObject> {

  // ...

  @Override public Iterator<SubObject> iterator() {
    return setOfObjects.iterator();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public SetOfObjects myFunction(**SetOfObjects aSet**){
    for (SubObject obj : aSet) {    <----ERROR
        //do something
    }
```

You are trying to iterate a loop using a Object instead it should be 
   list of Object.
   It has to be

```
public SetOfObjects myFunction(List<SetOfObjects> aSet){
    for (SubObject obj : aSet) {    
        //do iteration 
    }
```

Comment: I think you suggestion will fail at compile time

Comment: Please try in your ide . As i didn't think & wrote here.